# how to find multiple data in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I cannot see data matching status and name this way. When I run this, the status and name are searching separately. but I want to get the data matching both.

```
return await Product.find({
  $or: [
    { status: args.status },
    { product_name: args.product_name}
   ]
}).sort({ createdAt: "desc" });
```

I tried filter and aggregate but I could not get the correct data.

status can be `null`. `$and` it doesn't work for me.

**solved**

```
let filter = {};
if (args.status) {
  filter.status = args.status;
}
if (args.product_name) {
  filter.product_name = args.product_name;
}
const result = await Product.find({
  ...filter
}).sort({ createdAt: "desc" });

return result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find products where `status == args.status` **and** `product_name == args.product_name` you would pass a query object like this:

```
{
  status: args.status,
  product_name: args.product_name
}
```

***Edit***

It sounds like you want to build the filter document depending on available parameters. It might look something like this.

```
let filter = {}
if (args.status) {
  filter.status = args.status
}
if (args.product_name) {
  filter.product_name = args.product_name
}
```

You would then pass this filter object to the `find` call.

Comment: when I send just status data, it doesn't get any results.  @Montgomery Watts

Comment: clearly , I just want it to search for status when I send status, if I send two data I want to get the data that has two data. @Montgomery Watts

Comment: thanks man, i updated my post to help other people.